# Sharepoint topology setup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We experiencing issues at our client's sharepoint-on premise installation, and we're having difficulties reproducing it on our qa-lab (lack of SP knowlegde).
The endpoint is: http://a.sp.com/p1/p2/target and I need to get data on items in /target.

http://dom.sp.com/ is probably sharepoint instance as well, as we were able to obtain data (contained folders etc).
http://dom.sp.com/ cannot "see" /p1/p2/target (User can't navigate from http://dom.sp.com/ down to /p1/p2/target).

Can you direct me how to setup such a topology?

Comment: I assume target is the list or library you want to access, so p1 is a managed path and p2 is the site collection or p1 is a root site collection and p2 a subsite. If you could access the Central Administration of a.sp.com then go to the application settings and then View all Site Collections, you could find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the http://dom.sp.com/ is the root site collection under the web application, then you could create the subsite “p1” under the root site collection http://dom.sp.com/.

And then create the subsite “p2” under the site p1 http://dom.sp.com/p1/, and  then create the subsite ”target” under the site p2 http://dom.sp.com/p1/p2 .

Then when you access the site “target”, the url will be http://dom.sp.com/p1/p2/target .

If the  http://dom.sp.com/ is only the web application, then you could create site collection under the web application. And you can define the managed path as “p1” when creating site collection.

And create the site collection as “p2”. And then create subsite “target” under the site p2.

When you access the site “target”, the URL will be http://dom.sp.com/p1/p2/target.

[image]